# RS232 connection from PC to PLC slower than using USB2RS232 cable?

Tags: serial-port, plc

I had a PC connected to a PLC (Mitsubishi Q Series) via a USB2RS232 cable. The cable was plugged into the PC side, which was then plugged into a Serial cable and then into the PLC. I hade the baud rate set to 19200 and everything worked fine.
My problem was that every now and then the PC would blue screen on me. When I checked through the dump files the problem seemed to be related to the driver for the USB2RS232 cable (ftdi). I update to the latest driver but still bluescreening (Pc was running Windows 7).

Anyway I replaced the PC with another which had a dedicated RS232 port. Now I keep getting communication issues which is indicated by the response by the PLC. Just by chance I lowered the baud rate down to 9600 on both the PC and PLC. The issue seems to have gone away.

My question is why would removing the USB2RS232 cable cause me to have to slow down the communication? Both devices can communicate at speeds greater than 19200 and I would have thought going from serial port (PC) to serial port (PLC) with a serial cable would be better.

EDIT: Problem maybe solved - still testing

Thanks to some of the input from you guys, I may have solved the problem. Here are the following points I went by to get the speed back up to 19200 when using straight RS232 to RS232.

- Even though no noise was detected on the equipment, a shielded cable was used.
- The PC program would wait 100ms between sending data to the PLC. I read somewehere that 100ms is a good approx for PLC scan time.

Comment: What does that have to do with C# ? you need to provide related code to clarify the issue in question.

Comment: Sorry corrected, the program was with in c# and I was going to include some code but decided it was not needed so delete the code but forgot to delete the tag

Comment: It could have very well been the code itself. I assume it's a homebrew since you have the source, and not supplied by the PLC or driver manufacturer. If the noise checks out and there's no hardware issues, it almost certainly is related to your code.

Comment: I am mearly sending a command to the PLC and then waiting for a response. That doesn't explain an answer to my question, I'm asking why would removing one cable (USB2RS232), cause me to have to slow down the communication? What is the USB cable doing to allow me to communicate at greater speeds?

Comment: @Gaz83 Can you show us your code for sending and receiving characters?

Answer (score 3):

RS232 Communication between modern PLCs and modern computers is often a hassle. These are some things I look at what it's not working:

The cable. Lots of cables are nonstandard, and have nonstandard internal jumpers and whatnot that can increase error rates and lower throughput. It is possible that your USB converter is more advanced and is autodetecting something with your cable and compensating for it.

The OS on the PC. Windows versions newer than Windows 98 don't seem to have the best support for serial communications.

Interference. Be especially careful of drives near the comm line. If you are using unshielded cables, a drive that runs intermittently can cause exactly the problem you describe, where you get an intermittent failure, but no noise at all whe the equipment is idle and you go check.

Answer (score 2):

From your description I would guess that you have your equipment in a "noisy" environment - judging from the previous blue screens and now the issues with a regular RS232.

Have you tried to run the setup elsewhere with same hardware but other environment?

See if you can get a better isolated serial cable and/or use an EMF-meter to measure electric/magnetic fields around your setup.

Also worth to check out would be to put in another RS232 card in the PC to see if you have issues there, it could be that you had bad luck and the RS232 has broken.

### Edit

Are you sure the speed is higher than 9600 with the USB converter? maybe it has negotiated down the speed? (disclaimer: not sure what brand you are using and how intelligent it is).

Comment: Thats a point, I will get one of the Electronic engineers to knock me up a screen cable to see if that help. Unfortunatly this is one of those mini PC's so I can't add PCI cards etc.

Comment: One of the guys hooked up a scope and said the signal is noise free

Comment: I agree - I've seen this with other PLCs as well.  In electrically noisy environments it is not uncommon to get faster transfers at lower baud just because the error rate rises so quickly with increased transfer rates.

Comment: but I am not getting faster transfers I am getting slower. The issue is what is the USB cable doing to allow me to communicate faster?

Comment: @claptrap Yes I am sure its higher, the PLC serial port and my program are both set to 19200 baud rate.